# transformedValueClass to return Array of type AnyObject

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, core-data, nsvaluetransformer

I'm trying to implement `NSValueTransformer` class named `ArrayValueTransformer` which is meant to transform an Array which can contain any type of object in it as follows:

```
class ArrayValueTransformer : NSValueTransformer {
    override class func transformedValueClass() -> AnyClass {
        return Array<AnyObject>.self
    }
}
```

But the return statement gives this error:

```
Type 'Array<AnyObject>' does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject'
```

Answer (score 2):

**AnyClass** is a **typealias** for **AnyObject**.Type. **AnyObject** only represents the reference types in Swift such as classes. Where as **Array** in Swift are value type which cannot be represented by **AnyObject** rather you should use **Any**. You could use **NSArray** which is a class type in Objective C which is bridged nicely to Swift Array.

```
class ArrayValueTransformer : NSValueTransformer {

    override func transformedValue(value: AnyObject?) -> AnyObject? {
        guard let randomString = value as? String else { return nil }
        return split(randomString.characters, isSeparator: {$0 == " "}).map{ String($0) }
    }

    override func reverseTransformedValue(value: AnyObject?) -> AnyObject? {
        guard let randomArray = value as? [String] else { return nil }
        return randomArray.reduce(" ", combine: { "\($0!) \($1)" })
    }

    override class func transformedValueClass() -> AnyClass {
        return NSArray.self
    }
}

let transformer = ArrayValueTransformer()
let transformedValue = transformer.transformedValue("J A C K")!

let originalValue = transformer.reverseTransformedValue(transformedValue)
```

By the way, you can use AnyObject.self. The **transformdValue** and **reverseTransformedValue** has the return type of AnyObject?, So you would need to typecast it to your type any how.

Answer (score 0):

```
 override class func transformedValueClass() -> AnyClass {
    return NSArray.self
}
```